# Cross-Thread property behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows form with a text box `txtOutput`. I have some content in it. I have written a property to get and set the `txtOutput.Text` both from within the same thread and across threads like this:

```
public string OutputString
{
    get
    {
        string text = string.Empty;
        if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    text = txtOutput.Text;
                }));
        }
        else
        {
            text = txtOutput.Text;
        }
        return text;
    }
    set
    {
        if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    txtOutput.Text = value;
                }));
        }
        else
        {
            txtOutput.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If I set/get the property from the same thread, the behavior is as expected when calling the below function like `PrintMessage()`.

```
public void PrintMessage()
{
    MessageBox.Show(OutputString);
}
```

But when I call like this `new Thread(PrintMessage).Start()`. The `get` does not retrieve the value in the text box (i.e., the `MessageBox` shows empty string). When I do the same by keeping a breakpoint on the line:

```
txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    text = txtOutput.Text;
}));
```

while debug, the value is retrieved (i.e., the `MessageBox` shows the `txtOutput` content)

Should I `sleep` somewhere? Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're calling MessageBox.Show() with a reference to the text variable before the UI thread can handle the request you placed with the dispatcher. I would avoid using Thread.Sleep() as you could end up with some nasty side effects. Ideally you should re-factor your code to get rid of the property, which is synchronous, in favor of a more asynchronous solution. Something similar to the code below should give you the result you're looking for:

```
public void PrintMessage(Action<string> displayAction)
{
    string text = string.Empty;
    if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            displayAction.Invoke(txtOutput.Text);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        displayAction.Invoke(txtOutput.Text);
    }
}
```

And Invoke it:

```
// Get the text asynchronously
PrintMessage(s => MessageBox.Show(s));
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to implement the `set` property like this?

Comment: The only way, which I don't recommend, would be to block the calling thread by calling txtOutput.Invoke() instead of txtOutput.BeginInvoke() in the get accessor of the property.

Comment: It works. But why should not I use it? Why is it not recommended?

Comment: Your code should work fine if you use that, but normally it's assumed that property gets are relatively inexpensive operations. If you start blocking in a get accessor you could notice performance degradation as your application becomes more complex and other programmers use your class, not knowing this could block the thread. The rule I try to follow is if it's expensive put it in a method call, and depending on the situation (i.e. in the case of user interfaces and web apps) make these method calls asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasks with [TaskScheduler form UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx). When you pass the dispatcher form UI thread to task factory, this task performed in UI thread and return result to the thread where this task was created on.

```
namespace WpfTest {
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private readonly TaskScheduler _taskScheduler;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        _taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
    }

    public string Text {
        get {
            if (text.CheckAccess()) {
                return text.Text;
            }
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => text.Text, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Result;
        }
        set {
            if (text.CheckAccess()) {
                text.Text = value;
            } else {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => { text.Text = value; }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
        Text += "Test1";
        new Thread(() => { Text += "Test2"; }).Start();
    }
}
}
```